# Type of visa to apply to attend a conference in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, conferences, nepali-citizens

I am from Nepal and confused about the type of visa to apply to visit London, UK for a conference of three days. I have the letter of sponsorship.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and apply as a Standard Visitor.

It's best practices to examine the rules in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449641/20150803_Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_V.pdf) carefully. You should also read [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) to help you prepare your evidence.

Applications in Nepal are submitted at the [Visa Application Centre in Kathmandu](https://www.gov.uk/government/world-location-news/uk-visa-service-to-resume-from-british-embassy-kathmandu) and sent on to the visa section in New Delhi (or processed locally if the repairs in Kathmandu are finished).