# Visa type for Scotland to attend Conference from India

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, conferences

I am invited to attend a conference in Edinburgh. I am clear that I will be requiring UK standard Visa, after going through these links.
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

However, while booking an appointment I am confused with the Visa Category.
The purpose of my visit - Business (Academic) or Tourism?

**Conference** - General Studies and Status of Women

**Related to my Work** - No, this is a domain outside my work area.

**Profession** - Senior Analyst, Finance and IT domain

Since my work is not related, I am assuming that I cannot select Business(Academic).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Kindly guide, If I am missing something here?
I have also gone through below links (helpful, but I am from India) -

[UK visa type to attend conference and training in London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66470/uk-visa-type-to-attend-conference-and-training-in-london)

[Type of visa to apply to attend a conference in the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56155/type-of-visa-to-apply-to-attend-a-conference-in-the-uk)

Comment: Are you attending the conference solely because of personal interest?  If your attendance is in any way connected with your work then it's a business visit.  If it's purely personal then you could probably choose tourism.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am attending as per my personal interest. This clarifies my doubt

Comment: You are using the wrong form.  Please read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98219/what-is-the-correct-visa-for-a-spouse/98222#98222  and https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview), clearly states that you need a **UK Standard Visa** for attending conferences in the region.

> [image]

Comment: There is no option for standard, I have shown the screenshot above.

Comment: Please go through the doc. The standard visa comes under `Tourist and short stay visas`. So, it is the tourist visa :)

Comment: @ItiTyagi the fact that attending conferences is an allowed business visitor activity does not prevent it from also being an allowed tourist activity.

Comment: Please do not use pictures instead of text on SE sites, Dawny33- they cannot be searched. Can you quote the text?

Answer (score 2):

[image: They seem to contradict themselves]

They seem to contradict themselves. It says you can apply for a visa but not must. It says you can stay in UK for up to 6 months without a visa and can go to a conference, meeting or training.

Comment: Please [do not use pictures instead of text on SE sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), Julia - they cannot be searched. Can you quote the text?